# Remove cache with tags by cache key

Tags: laravel, caching

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache#removing-tagged-cache-items) says

> You may flush all items that are assigned a tag or list of tags. For example, this statement would remove all caches tagged with either people, authors, or both. So, both Anne and John would be removed from the cache:

```
Cache::tags(['people', 'authors'])->flush();
```

> In contrast, this statement would remove only cached values tagged with authors, so Anne would be removed, but not John:

```
Cache::tags('authors')->flush();
```

But doesn't talk about if you wanted to flush specifically `John` or `Anne`

**Is there still a way to remove by key?**

Because `Cache::forget('John');` does not work in this case.

Something like `Cache::tags(['authors'])->flush('John');` perhaps.

Or is the only practical way to make a unique tag which would just be the same as the key?

Comment: I think you're looking for  ``Cache::put('key', 'value');`` and ``Cache::forget('key');``

Comment: No, I need the tags because I need to ability to flush multiple caches where needed

Comment: ``Tags`` are used to group multiple ``key-value`` paired caches into one. If you want to remove an individual cache you can simply call ``Cache::forget('key');``

Comment: I tried that in Laravel 7 and didn't seem to work, however if I remove the tags the forget function worked

Comment: Then you don't seem to understand the concept of tags I guess. Or please explain your use case a little more clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234689/discussion-between-wanjia-and-omi-shah).

Comment: Cache::tags(['tag'])->flush('John'); would always be the same as Cache::forget('John'), that how a dictionary structure would work :/

Comment: @mrhn absolutely right

Comment: This is getting off topic, it's not a case if it would be the same or not it's about the that forget() on a tagged cache doesn't work and if there's a work around. I already explained in chat (3 comments up) why I need both to work.

Comment: But you are not really listening. If its the same, why do you not just use forget without using the tags method, you can still tag them when you save the keys?

Comment: I'm repeating myself, please click the "continue this discussion in chat" a few comment up for a detailed explanation as to why I need both tags and forget(). And forget about my suggestion which is irrelevant to the actual question